# Using single sign on permissions on the iphone on the server

Tags: iphone, ios, oauth, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication

If an mobile user have authorized the app for facebook via Single Sign On, is there a way the permissions can be used on the server side for offline access?

Scenario:

- user uses the mobile app
- user authenticates via SSO
- app needs to use the user's permission on the server to check for certain updates
- app pings the user via notifications if updates received

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You need to authorize at the app and obtain the Facebook token. Then you can send this token to your server and use it there without problems. You should ask for the offline_access permission if you want this token not to expire in a few hours.